# How is apply, bind and call methods available in Object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I was trying to understand prototypal inheritance in javascript and then I stumble upon apply method which is own property of `Function.prototype` but when I try to check property apply on `Object` it actually exist there as well. Now I am confused as I know that parent most object is `Object` not `Function`.

To try out what I am saying just run these in chrome console.

```
Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty('apply') // o/p --> true


    Object.hasOwnProperty('apply'); // o/p --> false
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('apply'); // o/p --> false
    Object.apply // o/p --> ƒ apply() { [native code] }
```

Comment: What kind of `Object` are you talking about? The constructor `new Object` is a function, therefore because `Function.prototype.hasOwnProperty('apply')`, `Object.apply` exists (but not `Object.prototype.apply` because `{}.apply` does not exist).

Comment: `Object` is a function ... try `console.log(typeof Object)` - it's not weird ... anything you can `new XXX()` is a function ... `new Object()` is perfectly cromulent ... but the result is an instance of an Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which `Object` you're talking about.

The *function* `Object` has `Function.prototype` in its prototype chain, `Object.apply` exists.

It doesn't exist, however, on an actual object. Therefore, `apply` can only be used with `Object` as a static method (because `apply` is not attached to `Object.prototype`):

```js
const objectFunctionHasApply = Object.apply || false;
const literalObjectHasApply = ({}).apply || false;
console.log(objectFunctionHasApply);
console.log(literalObjectHasApply);
```